# URLSession throws "cancelled" error during initial fetch [SwiftUI]

Tags: swift, urlsession

I am creating a SwiftUI App to show data from an API in a list as a way to practice MVVM. The App has a function in the viewModel that calls a service, and this service uses "try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)". The App also has a tab bar, with the first tab being the list.

Originally, the fetch data call to the viewModel was done in "ContentView" (first view containing the tab bar). The fetch worked fine, but this was making the entire screen reload (including the tab bar and some buttons) every time a new fetch from the API was done. To fix this, I moved the fetch data call to "HomeView" (child view containing the list). Now, only the list reloads when a new fetch is done. However, the initial fetch throws an error.localizedDescription of "cancelled". This generates an alert in my app (included in "HomeView"), which immediately disappears and the app works as intended. The error only happens during the initial fetch (when the App has just started). Subsequent fetch data calls work as intended and do not show any alerts.

I would really appreciate any insights on why is this error happening and how to fix it. You can find the relevant sections of the Service, ViewModel, ContentView and HomeView below.

Service

```
struct Network {

    func fetchResults() async throws -> Result {
    
        guard let url = URL(string: completeURL) else {
            throw NetworkError.failedToReadURL
        }

        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw NetworkError.invalidStatusCode
        }

        if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data) {
            return decodedResponse
        } else {
            throw NetworkError.failedToDecode
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
@MainActor
class ResultViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum State {
        case na
        case loading
        case success(data: [Result.Record])
        case failed(error: Error)
    }

    @Published private(set) var state: State = .na
    @Published var hasError: Bool = false

    private var service: Network

    init(service: Network) {
        self.service = service
    }

    // MARK: - ViewModel Fetches Result from Service
    func getResult() async {
        self.state = .loading
        self.hasError = false
    
        do {        
            let results = try await service.fetchResults()
            self.state = .success(data: results)
        } catch {
            self.state = .failed(error: error)
            self.hasError = true
        }
    }
}
```

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

HomeView

```
struct HomeView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = ResultViewModel(
        service: Network()
    )

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                switch viewModel.state {
                case .success(let data):
                    ListView(data: data)
                case .loading:
                    ProgressView()
                default:
                    Text("Something went wrong")
                }
            }
            .task {
                await viewModel.getResult()
            }
            .alert("Error", isPresented: $viewModel.hasError, presenting: viewModel.state) { detail in
                Button("Retry") {
                    Task {
                        await viewModel.getResult()
                    }
                }
            } message: { detail in
                if case let .failed(error) = detail {
                    Text(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try making Network a class rather than a struct.

Comment: The above is working for me, as is. The only thing I can guess is the `task` modifier, for which “If the task doesn’t finish before SwiftUI removes the view or the view changes identity, SwiftUI cancels the task.” And with structured concurrency, if the task is cancelled, the `URLSession` request will too.

Comment: @Rob Thank you! Based on your comment, I started removing modifiers from HomeView until I found the culprit. Turns out my .searchable modifier in the Group {} (Not included in the original post for the sake of simplification) was creating the error. I solved this by moving the .searchable modifier directly below ListView(data: data instead).